# beautifulsoup parse html content

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I need to get **date** out from each html files. 
I tried find_siblings('p'), but returns `None`.

Date is under tags below (mostly the third `p` tag) but sometimes is with the first tag of `id="a-body"`

```
<div class="sa-art article-width" id="a-body" itemprop="articleBody">
    <p class="p p1">text1</p>
    <p class="p p1">text2</p>
    <p class="p p1">
    January 6, 2009  8:00 am ET
    </p>
    ..
    ..
    ..
</div>
```

or

Inside the first tag but include other information.

```
<div class="sa-art article-width" id="a-body" itemprop="articleBody">
    <p class="p p1">
      participant text1 text2 text3 January  8, 2009  5:00 PM ET
    </p>
    <p class="p p1">text</p>
    <p class="p p1">text</p>
    ..
    ..
</div>
```

My code is just simply to find the third `p`, but if it's within the first `p` with other content, I don't know how to do it:

```
fo = open('C:/Users/output1/4069369.html', "r") 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(fo, "lxml")

d_date = soup.find_all('p')[2]
print d_date.get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide the website

Comment: please, provide your python code

Comment: @SergeiZ updated code

Comment: @ElvirMuslic I've already downloaded all webpage into each html file though. So I just provide the tags contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you have to find the element `p` with `date`, then you can work with a months list, like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
div_test='<div class="sa-art article-width" id="a-body" itemprop="articleBody">\
<p class="p p1">text1</p>\
<p class="p p1">\
  participant text1 text2 text3 January  8, 2009  5:00 a.m. EST\
</p>\
<p class="p p1">text2</p>\
<p class="p p1">\
January 6, 2009  8:00 pm ET\
</p></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(div_test, "lxml")
month_list = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']

def first_date_p():
    for p in soup.find_all('p',{"class":"p p1"}):
        for month in month_list:
            if month in p.get_text():
                first_date_p = p.get_text()
                date_start= first_date_p.index(month)
                date_text = first_date_p[date_start:]
                return date_text
first_date_p()
```

It will output the first `p` element which has `date`, no matter the element's position, in other words, it contains month:

```
u'January  8, 2009  5:00 a.m. EST'
```

Comment: It will print other text that contains month though. Can it only print the first find?

Comment: can it get rid of the texts and only keep date?

Comment: I found some files that no space between am and ET, which produce an error. Any way to solve it?

Comment: check the updated, in line `date_end`, you could expand more condition if you have other format.

Comment: What does index('amET') +4 or +3 mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145350/discussion-between-tiny-d-and-michael-lin).

Answer (score 0):

With provided code It's not really clear that really happens, but i guess, you are trying to find against root of page. try if it's work like this:

```
d_date = soup.find_all('div', { "id" : "a-body" })[0].find_all("p")[0] 
print d_date.get_text(strip=True)
```

**Update:**

```
for page in pages:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
    if soup.find_all("p")[2].get_text():
        d_date = soup.find_all("p")[2]
        print d_date.get_text(strip=True)
    else:
        d_date = soup.find_all("p")[0]
        print d_date.get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: It will only find the first tag (text1) though if date is in the 3rd tag.

Comment: If it's in the third 'p', works. If it's in the first 'p', return empty though.

Comment: When date is in  the first 'p' where is <div id="a-body" > have closing tag ? In both your sample div element dont have closing </div> tag. In second case, if p tags not inside this <div> - it will not work, May be you simply just need take first p on page, if date not in third

Comment: It always inside <div id="a-body">...</div> just sometimes appearred in the first 'p'

Comment: Problem was condition should be checked against.get_text(). Check also @Tiny.D solution may be it will work better for you. My code will make sense only third p tag will be empty

Answer (score 0):

It is better identify a unique common pattern to be use... if you cannot rely on tag's attribute why don't use the string? Each date end with a `ET` so use this info like this

```
tag_dates = soup.find_all(lambda t: str(t.string).endswith('ET'), string=True)

dates = [str(t.string) for t in tag_dates] # list of all dates
```